# How to select element that is placed before hovered element

Tags: html, css

I want to set visibility of "p" element on .img:hover.

HTML

```
<div class="imgCont">
    <div class="conoc">
        <p class="like">&#10084;</p> <!-- I want to select this "p" element on .img:hover -->
        <img class="img" src="uploads/img.jpg" alt="" >
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.like {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
}

.img:hover + .like {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: yours should work if you place the <p> element after your <img /> element. "+" selects the element immediately after the first selected element. As mentioned in the link above, .img:hover ~ .like will select every .like element that is preceded by an .img element.

Comment: I resolve problem. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You need to replace the p tag of the image

```
<div class="imgCont">
    <div class="conoc">
        <img class="img" src="uploads/img.jpg" alt="image" >
        <p class="like">&#10084;</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see it from [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mahdiihd/j3dcw7zx/1/) Online